# Object of class yii\db\Command could not be converted to string

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have got this error while using query in Yii 2.

This is my code for SQL query :

```
<?php $fines=Yii::$app->db->createCommand('select sum(fines) as fines from lib_chekout '); ?>
```

And this is code where i used that $fines variable :

```
<h4 class="pull-left" style="font-size: 20px"> Total fines Collected Till Today : </h4> <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 20px"> <?= $fines ?> </p>
```

Now the problem is, it shows error

> Object of class yii\db\Command could not be converted to string

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add [queryScalar()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html) after the command.
Like this:

```
<?php 
$fines=Yii::$app
            ->db
            ->createCommand('select sum(fines) as fines from lib_chekout ')
            ->queryScalar(); 
?>
```

and also change this  `>?` to `?>`