# yii\db\Command could not be converted to string - Insert - Yii2

Tags: yii2, transactions, insert

I'm refactoring some code which consists in multiple insert queries, to do so I'm converting every insert method that looks like this:

```
$code = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
                            ->insert('code', $codeData
                            )->execute();
```

To something like this:

```
$codeQuery = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
                            ->insert('code', $codeData);

return $codeQuery;
```

And in an another method which executes the transaction:

```
 $transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
            try{
                Yii::$app->db->createCommand($codeQuery)->execute();
                $transaction->commit();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $transaction->rollBack();
                throw $e;
            } catch (\Throwable $e) {
                $transaction->rollBack();
                throw $e;
            }
```

But I got the error:

> Object of class yii\db\Command could not be converted to string

This post: [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406486/object-of-class-yii-db-command-could-not-be-converted-to-string) doesn't really helped me.

I'm doubtful if that correct choice is to rewrite every single insert command in something that the transaction method can execute, or converting directly my current insert command output in something viable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already had assigned `$codeQuery = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->insert('code', $codeData)` than you don't need to pass $codeQuery into another createCommand method. This method can read string of sql as variable.

If you want to transform command into string, make a conversion:

```
$str = $codeQuery->getRawSql(); // get sql statement
$res = $codeQuery->execute(); // execute sql statement
```

Comment: Yes, I've resolved by executing directly $codeQuery in the transaction method.